# How to print error logs in output HTML file

Tags: java, html, xml

How to print error logs in output HTML file with the use of Java

I am trying to convert xml to html through the use of xslt.But the output i am gettign in html file.Now in java code i am handling some FileNotFoundexception also, now suppose in case if file not found exception came then i want that error to be thrown at output HTML page

As requested by.....PSB for the code

public class XmlToHtml {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
if (args.length == 3 && args.length !=0) {
    String dataXML = args[0];
    String inputXSL = args[1];
    String outputHTML = args[2];

    XmlToHtml xmltoHtml = new XmlToHtml();
    try {
        xmltoHtml.transform(dataXML, inputXSL, outputHTML);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("TransformerConfigurationException" + e);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("TransformerException" + e);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException" + e);
    }
} else {
    System.err.println("Wrong Input");
    System.err
            .println("Please Enter in the follwing format : Data.xml Input.xsl            Output.html");
}
}

    public void transform(String dataXML, String inputXSL, String outputHTML)
    throws FileNotFoundException, TransformerException,
    TransformerConfigurationException {
     TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslDoc = new StreamSource(inputXSL);
     Source xmlDoc = new StreamSource(dataXML);
     OutputStream htmlDoc = new FileOutputStream(outputHTML);
     Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
     transformer.transform(xmlDoc, new StreamResult(htmlDoc));
     Desktop dk = Desktop.getDesktop();
     try {
        dk.open(new File(outputHTML));

       } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Share some code, please.

Comment: Please share the code so that we can help, btw are you apache FOP for this task?

Comment: shared the code now,,,,,,,,